# How to properly check if a font can handle a codePoint in PdfBox

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I am attempting to write text to a PDF using NotoEmoji font only when Emojis are encountered. I am doing a check similar to the one below to determine when to use NotoEmoji instead of my default font. Here is a bit of code that reproduces my problem:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(
            new PDDocument(),
            ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf"),
            false);
    String hex = "01F302";
    int codepoint = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
    System.out.println("codepoint: " + codepoint);
    System.out.println("contains hex " + hex + ": " + font.hasGlyph(codepoint));

}
```

I would expect the output to be

```
codepoint: 127746
contains hex 01F302: true
```

Instead, the `hasGlyph` method is returning false. I have verified the font contains this emoji (closed umbrella). I don't know if I'm loading the font incorrectly or if I am completely misunderstanding how this works. This is my first time using PdfBox.

I'm using the following version of pdfbox

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

<-----------------------UPDATE----------------------->

Ok, I think I might have a solution to this, but I'd love for someone to explain it to me. I had been using hasGlyph to check whether a particular codePoint could be handled by the font. I think that is wrong.  I found a couple of SO questions that seem to suggest that. Instead, it appears something like `font.codeToCID(codepoint) > 0` will work. However, I'm not sure if it's reliable. Also `font.codeToGID(codepoint)` does not work and I don't know why. Here is a snippet similar to the one above to demonstrate my proposed solution:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(
                new PDDocument(),
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf"),
                false);
        String hex = "01F302";
        int codepoint = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
        System.out.println("codepoint: " + codepoint);
        System.out.println("hasGlyph(0): " + font.hasGlyph('0'));
        System.out.println("cid: " + font.codeToCID(codepoint));
        System.out.println("gid: " + font.codeToGID(codepoint));
        System.out.println("can Encode: " + (font.codeToCID(codepoint) > 0));
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
codepoint: 127746
hasGlyph(0): true
cid: 62210
gid: 0
can Encode: true
```

In addition, I have updated the title of my question to more accurately reflect the problem I am trying to solve, I think.

Comment: Hmm. What does `Font.canDisplay(codepoint)` say?

Comment: Yes, I see that. Try it and see. In a sense you're testing the wrong thing but I agree it doesn't inspire confidence.

Comment: The parameter is the character code in a PDF, not the unicode. Use PDPageContentStream.showText() and catch the IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: @user16320675 `font.hasGlyph('0')` returns true. I assume that means the font is actually loaded.

Also, when I print `System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf"))`, I get the file reference as expected.